# What determines the default Site Collection Administrators?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

This is for SharePoint 2013. Every time a new site collection is created, there are 3 user accounts that are automatically set as the Site Administrators under `Site Settings > Site Collection Administrators` If I check the `Site Collection Administrators` from `Central Administration` I only see 2 of the 3 users. How does SharePoint determine these users? Where and how can I change the users that are automatically created as `Site Collection Administrators`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is true. When you create the site collection during this you have to mentioned the primary and secondary Site collection administrators. Once site collection created then you will see the both account under site collection admin from site settings.

Just, I created a brand new site collection with primary site collection admin (no secondary) after that when i checked from site settings, i am seeing only one account.

Couple of things to check.

- How you are creating the site collections? central admin or pwoershell? if power-shell, then what is script?
- Are you know about the account name?
- is their any customization?

Comment: Your're right. I should of tried a test collection. So I created a test Site Collection assigning only a primary site collection administrator and that was the only user under `Site Collection Administrators`. Perhaps my username was added to all site collections through a script from the previous admin?

Comment: Yup, there should be some script or any thing similar this can add extra admins...if the above is helpful then upvote and mark the answer.